# What does this use of static mean in a Java class (not in a method)?

Tags: java, static

I'm seeing code like this at the beginning of a Java class.
This is clearly not a method.
What does it do?

```
static {
    // Grab the source ordering and create a lookup table
    // e.g. x => 0, z => 1, a => 2...
    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.SOURCE_ORDER.length; i++) {
        sourceSortOrderMap.put(Constants.SOURCE_ORDER[i], i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a *static initializer block*.

Comment: Have you tried reading the Tutorial or the JLS? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html You might be amazed at how useful the documentation can be.

Comment: @LewBloch I thought I did - must have missed it.